# TransactionManagementError:This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active while running unit test cases

Tags: python, django, pytest

I am getting this error while I am trying to run unit test case using pytest.
It works fine in my project but raises an error while running test case.

My code is as following:

```
def saveEvents(request, request_data):
    transaction.set_autocommit(autocommit=False)
    try:
        # here is my code
    except Exception as inst:
        transaction.rollback()
        # code
    transaction.commit()
    return something
```

I read all the solutions of this type of questions, but I am puzzled why its not working with pytest. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If you are testing code that manually manages transactions, you should mark your test as follows:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def my_test():
   ...
```

See [the pytest-django docs](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#testing-transactions) for more info.

Note that you may be able to restructure your code and use `with transaction.atomic():` inside a try.. except block instead of doing manual transaction management. See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) for examples.

Comment: hello, I tried your suggestions, @pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True), its not working, by using with transaction.atomic() its working fine, but why transaction.set_autocommit(autocommit=False) is not working with pytest?

Comment: I can't tell why it's not working from the information you've given.

Comment: @DikshaJiwane if you add more information, e.g. a stack trace, it would be easier to help.